# Splitting up a project into multiple smaller projects

Tags: version-control

I have a library containing a few classes. Now I want to split up this library into two separate libraries. What is the correct/best way to handle this in combination with source control?

My initial thought is to create a new repository for each new project and in the initial commit mention that it was split of from a now unmaintained project.
While I only have a few commits so far, an issue with this method is that the history of the project is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which version control you are using. For instance, in git you can use filter-branch to do the trick.

You can make a copy of the original repository, then use git filter-branch to keep the history of the part you are interested in and dropping everything else.

```
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter mydir1
$ git gc --aggressive
$ git prune
```

Beware this is destructive. You will see a considerable reduction of the repository size, only having the history of mydir1 and removing all those unreachable objects.

Then, repeat the same for other libraries/subdirectories. In that way, you will keep only the history that belongs to each part/library/directory.

If you are using a different version control system, then you have to figure out the equivalent way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb I follow depends on whether you will be developing and/or deploying the libraries independently.  If you are separating the libraries simply for code organization and the code is deployed as a single solution, then there is no need or benefit to creating separate repositories.

On the other hand, if you will be versioning and releasing the libraries independently, then having the code in separate repositories helps this.  So, for instance, if you are separating the code because some of it belongs in a share framework, then put the framework code in its own repository. This will allow you to maintain, build and release the framework separate from any applications that are built using the framework.

HTH

Comment: I will be deploying the libraries independently. Do you have a suggestion on what method to use for this?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new repository but also you can create new projects under the same repository and delete the old one in time. actually, that's up to you. if you see the previous project as test level or pre-alpha stage, you may want to create a new repository. but other than that, using the same repository is very likely for this situation.